# Variável indefinida, como posso resolver?

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte código:

```php
<?php
    
    $perfilUser = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `perfil_user`");
    $perfilUser->execute();
    $perfilUser = $perfilUser->fetchAll();

    if(isset($_POST['usuario_texto'])){
        $pf_foto = $_POST['pf_foto'];
        $pf_nome = $_POST['pf_nome'];
        $pf_cargo = $_POST['pf_cargo'];
        $pdo->exec("DELETE FROM `perfil_user`");
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `perfil_user` VALUES (null,?,?,?)");
        $sql->execute(array($pf_foto,$pf_nome,$pf_cargo));
    }
    
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="pf_foto" value="<?php echo $pf_foto; ?>" placeholder="Foto do perfil">
    <input type="text" name="pf_nome" value="<?php echo $pf_nome; ?>" placeholder="Nome">
    <input type="text" name="pf_cargo" value="<?php echo $pf_cargo; ?>" placeholder="Cargo">

    <input type="hidden" name="usuario_texto">
    <input type="submit" name="acao" value="Salvar">
</form>
```

O que estou fazendo é obtendo as informações da tabela **perfil_user** é **pf_foto**, **pf_nome** e **pf_cargo** e editando isso com o `form` e mostrando as informações no próprio `input`.

Mas, aparece este aviso na linha dos inputs onde estou chamando as informações com `value="<?php echo $pf_foto; ?>"`, `value="<?php echo $pf_nome; ?>"` e `value="<?php echo $pf_cargo; ?>"` da tabela e retorna o seguinte aviso:

```
Undefined variable $pf_foto
Undefined variable $pf_nome
Undefined variable $pf_cargo
```

Não estou entendendo o que está acontecendo, para mim o código ta certo. Podem me ajudar nessa por favor?

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128596/discussion-on-question-by-isaias-santos-variavel-indefinida-como-posso-resolver) - Quem quiser acompanhar ou acrescentar algo pode utilizar o link fornecido.